# Why temperature gets so hot a fraction of seconds right after big bang?

Tags: temperature, big-bang

I read that right at the moment of big bang, time and space are created and there is only quantum fluctuation, so there should be no temperature because photon and many elementary particles did not yet exist until a fraction of second later. But I like to know that during this earliest epoch, why temperature becomes so hot in the first place? I'm imagining hawking radiation because I think the condition at the moment of big bang resembles micro black hole only different the latter explodes rather than balloons as it evaporate.

Answer (score 0):

> because photon and many elementary particles did not yet exist until a fraction of second later.

You say particles did not exist at the big bang. They did, just not the photon. However there could have been other particles. This is because all quantum fluctuations and vibrations in the quantum field means that particles were created. The field at the moment of the big bang is called the inflaton field.

So all in all there could have been different particles at the start of the big bang, completely different from standard model particles though. They treat it as if there were no particles and there were quantum fluctuations, however these quantum fluctuations were caused by energy and those quantum fluctuations are particles.

So back to the question of temperature, the temperature of the early universe is probably measured by the amount of fluctuations and "inflaton particles" that existed at the start of the universe.